# Design pattern for argument processing

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a program in Java used as a command line application.
I am using [jopt](https://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple) for argument processing. 
When getting the values from Jopt the code gets ugly because of the of multiple cases depending of the values of argument to choose an execution path.

Here is the method responsible for choosing what will be the next step based on the values of arguments:

```
private void processArgs(String args[])  {
      .......
     if (argsList.contains(VERSION)) {
        showVersion();
        return;
    }

    if (argsList.contains(SHOWENV)) {
        showEnv();
    }

    if (parsed.has(TARGET_LANG)) {
        String targetedLang = _targetLangOptionSpec.value(parsed);

        if (!JAVA.equalsIgnoreCase(targetedLang))
        {
             execJava();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (parsed.has(TARGET)) {
        processTargets();
        return;
    }

    if (parsed.has(EXEC)) {
        processExec();
    }

    if (parsed.has(CONSOLIDATE)) {
        consolidate();
    }
    ......
   }
```

I was wondering if this case was already treated by some design pattern.

I have looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421/what-is-the-design-pattern-for-processing-command-line-arguments) but there is no clear solution proposed.

Comment: The Apache commons CLI Library has very good CommandLine processing utilities, if you haven't come across it. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Bajal I already use Jopt java for handling the processing of the arguments. My problem is the best way of handling the multiplicity of execution cases depending on the values of the arguments.

Comment: Google *strategy pattern*

Answer (score -1):

One option is to create a separate class which parses the arguments. You can then query it's state to determine which execution cases should be used.

This approach separates parsing from execution, which I believe is good design (correct me if I'm wrong).