# How to separate parameters from a command in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for an address book in Java. The user will enter commands such as add-addressbook . The main problem I'm having is knowing which command is entered and taking the parameters from the command and putting them into methods. Not all commands have the same number of parameters. There is a space between the command and the parameters. The parameters are separated by exactly one comma. This code works when the user enters everything properly but returns an error otherwise. Is there a better way to do this?

```
while (!input.equals("quit")) {
            String[] data = input.split(" ", 2);
            ArrayList<String> listofdata = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data[1].split(",")));
            switch (data[0]) {
            case "add-addressbook":
                String nameofBook = listofdata.get(0);
                c.addBook(nameofBook);
                break;
             case "add-contact":
                String nameofBook2 = listofdata.get(0);
                String nameofContact = listofdata.get(1);
                String email = listofdata.get(2);
                String phone = listofdata.get(3);
                c.addPerson(nameofBook2, nameofContact, email, phone);
                break;
             //rest of code
             }
```

Comment: To clarify, expected usage is similar to `add-contact book1,First Last,name@blah.com,123-456-7890`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the design pattern for processing command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421/what-is-the-design-pattern-for-processing-command-line-arguments)

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes. There is a certain format required, which I specified in another class using regex and have appropriate error messages in case the user entered the details in another format (In this case the phone number you entered wouldn't work, but that's inconsequential to my question)

Comment: @jaco0646 - This question does not appear to be about command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a common interface `Command` with method that accepts either `String` or `List<String>`. And several separate implementations for each command.

And then each concrete implementation will parse its parameter and either process it or throw exception (or return `false` or `String` with error message).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you be able to link to an example of this being used?

Comment: @RakoonBerry this is a link to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Java but you can easily Google more code examples if needed

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm just starting out with programming so the help is appreciated :)