# Best way to read commands from a string and execute their respective functions in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The language is pretty much irrelevant here but I was wondering what was the best way of doing this.

Let's say I have a file with all the commands of a dog like this:

```
bark 10
sit
sit
lay side 17
bark 100
jump
```

And we have their respective functions programmed in C# or whatever language.

What's the best way to go through this list of strings and run their respective functions?

The most obvious solution to this would be to just do an if else chain or a switch statement. Is there a better way for this?

```
switch (command)
{
    case "bark":
        (...) parse remaining args
        Bark(arg);
        break;
    case "lay":
        (...) parse remaining args
        Lay(arg1, arg2);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("error");
        break;
}
```

I feel this is a little hacky. Is there an alternative or some kind of design pattern that fixes this issue in a clean way?

Comment: Hmm, just an idea: You could try to create a dictionary of the methods with their names as key and then look it up in that dictionary. But if this is better or worse depends on the metric used and in the end may still be significantly opinion based I guess.

Comment: You _could_ use a command line framework / library like [CliFx](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx) or [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the design pattern for processing command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421/what-is-the-design-pattern-for-processing-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Honestly I don't want to use libraries because I want to understand how to do it by myself. Is the command design pattern a good idea? Or template?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name of the function you can do this:

```
Type tp = this.GetType();
MethodInfo method = tp.GetMethod(methodName);
method.Invoke(this, yourParams);
```

Comment: Be aware that this might have the side effect that it wouldn't only allow to execute methods that are explicitly exposed but any (of the type) as long as one knows the name. This may or may not be wanted and may not or may be a (severe) issue.