# How to design a cli option combination handler in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, apache-commons-cli

I have the necessity to execute some functions based on a particular CLI combination options (I use the Apache Commons CLI library).

```
myprogram -a -b ptionArgument -c
myprogram -a -c
myprogram -d optionArgument1 optionArgument2
```

To manage this situation, I have a very long list of "else if" based on a particular combination, all in my main function:

```
if (line.hasOption('a') && line.hasOption('b') && line.hasOption('c')){
   method1();
   method2();
 }
else if (line.hasOption('a') && line.hasOption('c')){
    method4();
 }
else if (line.hasOption('d')){
    method1();
    method4();
 }
....
```

Is there a better way to design this? (by using some design pattern for example).

Comment: You might find that you can externalise the `line.hasOption('a')` into a variable like `hasA` which will make it easier to read and to understand, or you can have a `hasA` test, then do the `b` and `c` tests inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the design pattern for processing command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421/what-is-the-design-pattern-for-processing-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Not really, because i already have another class for processing commands (a controller class). My problem is how instantiate the right method of controller class based on an input. @jaco0646

Answer (score 1):

I would come up with this creating `CombinationHandler` interface with `handle()` method and creating **Map**, where arguments is the key and `CombinationHandler`'s are values.
After that you can simply add different combinations of `CombinationHandler`'s to each argument combination and invoke them

```
    interface CombinationHandler {
    void handle();
    // or declare other method signatures
}

public class CombinationComposer  {

    /* key is a merged combination of arguments*/
    private Map<String, List<CombinationHandler>>  handlingStrategies = new HashMap<>();

    public void execute(String arguments) {
        handlingStrategies.getOrDefault(arguments, new ArrayList<>())
                .forEach(CombinationHandler::handle);
    }
    
    public CombinationComposer() {
        handlingStrategies.put("abc", Lists.asList(
                () -> System.out.println(1),
                () -> System.out.println(2))
        );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String argsString; //squashing array
    new CombinationComposer().execute(argsString);
}
```